# Python module functions used in unexpected ways

Tags: python

Based on ["Split a string by spaces in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209/split-a-string-ignoring-quoted-sections#6243), which uses *shlex.split* to split a string with quotes smartly, I would be interested in hearing about other common tasks solved by non-obvious standard library functions.

If this turns into [Module of The Week](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/PyMOTW/), that's fine too.

Answer (score 7):

I was quite surprised to learn that you could use the bisect module to do a very fast binary search in a sequence. It's documentation doesn't say anything about it:

> This module provides support for maintaining a list in sorted order without having to sort the list after each insertion.

The usage is very simple:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> lst = [4, 7, 10, 23, 25, 100, 103, 201, 333]
>>> bisect.bisect_left(lst, 23)
3
```

You have to remember though, that it's quicker to linearly look for something in a list goes item by item, than sorting the list and then doing a binary search on it. The first option is O(n), the second is O(nlogn).

Comment: Is it true then that the bisect.insort() is also O(log n)?

Answer (score 4):

Oft overlooked modules, uses and tricks:

collections.defaultdict(): for when you want missing keys in a dict to have a default value.

functools.wraps(): for writing decorators that play nicely with introspection.

posixpath: the os.path module for POSIX systems. You can use it for manipulating POSIX paths (including URI elements) even on Windows and other non-POSIX systems.

ntpath: the os.path module for Windows; usable for manipulation of Windows paths on non-Windows systems.

(also: macpath, for MacOS 9 and earlier, os2emxpath for OS/2 EMX, but I'm not sure if anyone still cares.)

pprint: more structured printing of the repr() of containers makes debugging much easier.

imp: all the tools you need to write your own plugin system or make Python import modules from arbitrary archives.

rlcompleter: getting tab-completion in the normal interactive interpreter. Just do "import readline, rlcompleter; readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')"

the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable: can be set to the path to a file that will be executed (in the main namespace) when entering the interactive interpreter; useful for putting things in like the rlcompleter recipe above.

Answer (score 4):

I use itertools (especially cycle, repeat, chain) to make python behave more like R and in other functional / vector applications.  Often this lets me avoid the overhead and complication of Numpy.

```
# in R, shorter iterables are automatically cycled
# and all functions "apply" in a "map"-like way over lists
> 0:10 + 0:2
 [1]  0  2  4  3  5  7  6  8 10  9 11
```

Python
    #Normal python
    In [1]: range(10) + range(3)
    Out[1]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2]

```
## this code is terrible, but it demos the idea.
from itertools import cycle
def addR(L1,L2):
    n = max( len(L1), len(L2))
    out = [None,]*n
    gen1,gen2 = cycle(L1), cycle(L2)
    ii = 0
    while ii < n:
        out[ii] = gen1.next() + gen2.next()
        ii += 1
    return out

In [21]: addR(range(10), range(3))
Out[21]: [0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found struct.unpack to be a godsend for unpacking binary data formats after I learned of it!

Answer (score 2):

[getpass](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-getpass.html) is useful for determining the login name of the current user.

[grp](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-grp.html) allows you to lookup Unix group IDs by name, and vice versa.

[dircache](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-dircache.html) might be useful in situations where you're repeatedly polling the contents of a directory.

[glob](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-glob.html) can find filenames matching wildcards like a Unix shell does.

[shutil](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-shutil.html) is useful when you need to copy, delete or rename a file.

[csv](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-csv.html) can simplify parsing of delimited text files.

[optparse](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-optparse.html) provides a reliable way to parse command line options.

[bz2](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-bz2.html) comes in handy when you need to manipulate a bzip2-compressed file.

[urlparse](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-urlparse.html) will save you the hassle of breaking up a URL into component parts.

Comment: dircache is [deprecated in 2.6 and removed from 3.0](http://docs.python.org/library/dircache.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've found [sched module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-sched.html) to be helpful in cron-like activities. It simplifies things a lot. Unfortunately I found it too late.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other examples are merely overlooked, not unexpected uses for module.

fnmatch, like shlex, can be applied in unexpected ways.  fnmatch is a kind of poor-person's RE, and can be used for more than matching files, it can compare strings with the simplified wild-card patterns.

Answer (score 1):

One function I've come to appreciate is string.translate.  Its very fast at what it does, and useful anywhere you want to alter or remove characters in a string. I've just used it in a seemingly inapplicable [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89909/in-python-how-to-i-verify-that-a-string-only-contains-letters-numbers-underscor#92000) and found it beat all the other solutions handily.

The downside is that its API is a bit clunky, but this is improving in Py2.6 / Py3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The [pickle](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-pickle.html) module is pretty awesome

Answer (score 1):

complex numbers. (The complexobject.c defines a class, so technically it's not a module). Great for 2d coordinates, with easy translation/rotations etc

eg.

```
TURN_LEFT_90= 1j
TURN_RIGHT_90= -1j

coord= 5+4j # x=5 y=4
print coord*TURN_LEFT_90
```