# How to parse strings to look like sys.argv

Tags: python, parsing, argv

I would like to parse a string like this:

```
-o 1  --long "Some long string"
```

into this:

```
["-o", "1", "--long", 'Some long string']
```

or similar.

This is different than either getopt, or optparse, which *start* with sys.argv parsed input (like the output I have above).  Is there a standard way to do this?  Basically, this is "splitting" while keeping quoted strings together.

My best function so far:

```
import csv
def split_quote(string,quotechar='"'):
    '''

    >>> split_quote('--blah "Some argument" here')
    ['--blah', 'Some argument', 'here']

    >>> split_quote("--blah 'Some argument' here", quotechar="'")
    ['--blah', 'Some argument', 'here']
    '''
    s = csv.StringIO(string)
    C = csv.reader(s, delimiter=" ",quotechar=quotechar)
    return list(C)[0]
```

Comment: My own true forgetfulness revealed:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92533, has me using shlex.split.  Clearly I just forgot about it.

Comment: If what you actually need is "to process options" and not just "to parse strings on commandline", you could consider http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I believe you want the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('-o 1 --long "Some long string"')
['-o', '1', '--long', 'Some long string']
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew there was something like this!

Comment: That's great, except that it doesn't seem to support Unicode strings. The doc says that Python 2.7.3 support Unicode strings, but I'm trying it and `shlex.split(u'abc 123 →')` gives me a `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Comment: I guess `list(a.decode('utf-8') for a in shlex.split(u'abc 123 →'.encode('utf-8')))` will work.

Answer (score 3):

Before I was aware of [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split), I made the following:

```
import sys

_WORD_DIVIDERS = set((' ', '\t', '\r', '\n'))

_QUOTE_CHARS_DICT = {
    '\\':   '\\',
    ' ':    ' ',
    '"':    '"',
    'r':    '\r',
    'n':    '\n',
    't':    '\t',
}

def _raise_type_error():
    raise TypeError("Bytes must be decoded to Unicode first")

def parse_to_argv_gen(instring):
    is_in_quotes = False
    instring_iter = iter(instring)
    join_string = instring[0:0]

    c_list = []
    c = ' '
    while True:
        # Skip whitespace
        try:
            while True:
                if not isinstance(c, str) and sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
                    _raise_type_error()
                if c not in _WORD_DIVIDERS:
                    break
                c = next(instring_iter)
        except StopIteration:
            break
        # Read word
        try:
            while True:
                if not isinstance(c, str) and sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
                    _raise_type_error()
                if not is_in_quotes and c in _WORD_DIVIDERS:
                    break
                if c == '"':
                    is_in_quotes = not is_in_quotes
                    c = None
                elif c == '\\':
                    c = next(instring_iter)
                    c = _QUOTE_CHARS_DICT.get(c)
                if c is not None:
                    c_list.append(c)
                c = next(instring_iter)
            yield join_string.join(c_list)
            c_list = []
        except StopIteration:
            yield join_string.join(c_list)
            break

def parse_to_argv(instring):
    return list(parse_to_argv_gen(instring))
```

This works with Python 2.x and 3.x. On Python 2.x, it works directly with byte strings and Unicode strings. On Python 3.x, it *only* accepts [Unicode] strings, not `bytes` objects.

This doesn't behave exactly the same as shell argv splitting—it also allows quoting of CR, LF and TAB characters as `\r`, `\n` and `\t`, converting them to real CR, LF, TAB (`shlex.split` doesn't do that). So writing my own function was useful for my needs. I guess `shlex.split` is better if you just want plain shell-style argv splitting. I'm sharing this code in case it's useful as a baseline for doing something slightly different.