# split function settings

Tags: c#, split

I have a list string full of a range of different types of data. I'm reading into the list string line at a time and with each line i split it using

`string[] tableNa = line.Split(',');`

this gets all the different pieces of data in a line that are seperated by commas. however i have some lines like this:

`47,493,'1 = EMPTY, 2 = SEND, 3 = SENDING, 4 = SENT, 5 = NOTSENT.                        ',0,`

and i would like the split to not work within the quote marks,as i need to keep this as one piece of data. Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209/split-a-string-ignoring-quoted-sections

The replies there may be of some help to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible?

It's clearly possible to do this - but not with `string.Split` and nothing else.

If you want CSV parsing, you should find a good (possibly open source) CSV parsing library. I'm sure there are plenty around, and they're likely to be more reliable than anything you *incidentally* create as part of trying to provide more concrete business value.

Answer (score 2):

[split a comma-separated string with both quoted and unquoted strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776458/split-a-comma-separated-string-with-both-quoted-and-unquoted-strings)

Specifically, this (Regex looks terrifying, I know, but its relatively simple):

```
public void SplitCSV(string input)
{
    Regex csvSplit = new Regex("(?:^|,)(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^,]*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    foreach (Match match in csvSplit.Matches(input))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value.TrimStart(','));
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SplitCSV("111,222,\"33,44,55\",666,\"77,88\",\"99\"");
}
```