# Loading CSV in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to search the penultimate row in the first.csv which date is **1975-01-03** and the Lemon value is **17.0**, after I search in the second.csv the same date which lemon is **19.0**

After catching both values, I compute the difference **17.0 - 19.0 = -2.0**

The next step is to sum the difference **-2** to all Lemon's values in second.csv from the date **1975-01-03** to the end **1975-01-09**

The final step is to write the third.csv where we add the first.csv until the date **1975-01-02** and the sum we've done with second.csv from **1975-01-03** to the end **1975-01-09**

first.csv

```
Date,Lemon
1974-12-31,19.0
1975-01-02,18.0
1975-01-03,17.0
1975-01-06,16.0
```

second.csv

```
Date,Lemon
1975-01-02,18.0
1975-01-03,19.0
1975-01-06,19.5
1975-01-07,19.5
1975-01-08,18.0
1975-01-09,17.0
```

third.csv

```
Date,Lemon
1974-12-31,19.0
1975-01-02,18.0
1975-01-03,17.0
1975-01-06,17.5
1975-01-07,17.5
1975-01-08,16.0
1975-01-09,15.0
```

All in all, the read from CSV is not as important as to obtain the third result in an Array, DataTable, Dictionary or whatever. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702573/importing-csv-data-into-c-sharp-classes

Comment: CSVHelper will load to `IEnumerable<DatedLemon>` with just a few lines of code

Comment: A csv file is just text, you can read it like any other with File.ReadAllLines. Furthermore, since it is separated by comma's you can do string.split() based on spaces and commas to separate each CSV into string arrays, lists. dictionaries or whatever you prefer.  From there its just grabbed the values at the right indices and then create your result file and go.

Comment: Honestly though, this reads a lot like someone's college homework.  ಠ__ಠ

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett I study veterinary, this is hobby stuff :)

Comment: Okay, regarding your question, reading stuff into dictionaries is easy enough, but can you talk about how you want to store intermediate results like from your sums and such and name them so that I can better understand your question. I am already working on code for an answer.

Comment: "The next step is to sum the difference -2 to all Lemon's values in second.csv from the date 1975-01-03 to the end 1975-01-09"  Where are we storing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a handy `struct` to make the coding easier:

```
public struct Line
{
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public decimal Lemon;
}
```

Then you can write a simple function to load your CSV files:

```
Func<string, Line[]> readCsv =
    fn =>
        File
            .ReadLines(fn)
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(x => x.Split(','))
            .Select(y => new Line()
            {
                Timestamp = DateTime.Parse(y[0]),
                Lemon = decimal.Parse(y[1])
            })
            .ToArray();
```

Now the rest is just a reading the files and a couple of LINQ queries before writing out the results:

```
Line[] first = readCsv(@"C:\_temp\first.csv");
Line[] second = readCsv(@"C:\_temp\second.csv");

Line difference =
(
    from pen in first.Skip(first.Length - 2).Take(1)
    from mtch in second
    where mtch.Timestamp == pen.Timestamp
    select new Line()
    {
        Timestamp = pen.Timestamp,
        Lemon = pen.Lemon - mtch.Lemon
    }
).First();

IEnumerable<string> result =
    new [] { "Date,Lemon" }
        .Concat(
            first
                .Where(x => x.Timestamp < difference.Timestamp)
                .Concat(
                    second
                        .Where(x => x.Timestamp >= difference.Timestamp)
                        .Select(x => new Line()
                        {
                            Timestamp = x.Timestamp,
                            Lemon = x.Lemon + difference.Lemon
                        }))
                .Select(x => String.Format(
                    "{0},{1}",
                    x.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                    x.Lemon)));

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\_temp\third.csv", result);
```

The result I get is:

```
Date,Lemon
1974-12-31,19.0
1975-01-02,18.0
1975-01-03,17.0
1975-01-06,17.5
1975-01-07,17.5
1975-01-08,16.0
1975-01-09,15.0
```

Comment: @RamónTaríAgulló - Can you explain that further please?

Comment: Yes, you use the date required or position, in this case the penultime, as "variable" like in `from pen in first.Skip(first.Length - 2).Take(1)` am I correct?

PS: your code works for me

Comment: @RamónTaríAgulló - Yes, that's correct. Glad to hear that it works.

Comment: I'm understanding your code, so it has structures,  a ˋFunc<T, TResult>ˋ that uses lambda expressions and put the results in an array. Then the ˋLine difference =ˋ that is a LINQ query syntax. ˋIEnumerable <string>ˋ that is a LINQ method syntax.  Maybe you can give me more precise information, it seems that LINQ is useful to work with data in an understadable way. You may say me a place to start learning this, Thanks

Comment: @RamónTaríAgulló - I would download [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and run thru the samples it provides.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, I strongly advice you to do this exercice by yourself by learning about LINQ (just google it). If you are stuck or can't find the solution here is a way to do it :

```
class LemonAtDate
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public LemonAtDate(DateTime Date, double Value)
    {
        this.Date = Date;
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    public static List<LemonAtDate> LoadFromFile(string filepath)
    {
        IEnumerable<String[]> lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filepath).Select(a => a.Split(','));

        List<LemonAtDate> result = new List<LemonAtDate>();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (String[] line in lines)
        {
            index++;
            if (index == 1) continue; //skip header

            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(line[0], "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            double value = Double.Parse(line[1], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            result.Add(new LemonAtDate(date, value));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void WriteToFile(IEnumerable<LemonAtDate> lemons, string filename)
    {
        //Write to file
        using (var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
        {
            foreach (LemonAtDate lemon in lemons)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Date,Lemon");//Header

                string date = lemon.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                string value = lemon.Value.ToString();

                string line = string.Format("{0},{1}", date, value);
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Load first file
    List<LemonAtDate> firstCsv = LemonAtDate.LoadFromFile("first.csv");

    //Load second file
    List<LemonAtDate> secondCsv = LemonAtDate.LoadFromFile("second.csv");

    //We need at least two rows
    if (firstCsv.Count >= 2)
    {
        //Penultimate row in first file
        LemonAtDate lemonSecondLast = firstCsv[firstCsv.Count - 2];

        //Find the value 19 in the second file
        LemonAtDate lemonValue19 = secondCsv.Where(x => x.Value == 19).FirstOrDefault();

        //Value found
        if (lemonValue19 != null)
        {
            double delta = lemonSecondLast.Value - lemonValue19.Value;

            //Get the items between the dates and add the delta
            DateTime dateStart = new DateTime(1975, 1, 3);
            DateTime dateEnd = new DateTime(1975, 1, 9);
            IEnumerable<LemonAtDate> secondFileSelection = secondCsv.Where(x => x.Date >= dateStart && x.Date <= dateEnd)
                                                          .Select(x => { x.Value += delta; return x; });

            //Create third CSV
            List<LemonAtDate> thirdCsv = new List<LemonAtDate>();

            //Add the rows from the first file until 1975-01-02
            DateTime threshold = new DateTime(1975, 1, 2);
            thirdCsv.AddRange(firstCsv.Where(x => x.Date <= threshold));

            //Add the rows from the second file
            thirdCsv.AddRange(secondFileSelection);

            //Write to file
            LemonAtDate.WriteToFile(thirdCsv, "third.csv");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that you find the value **19.0** manually, it's better for me to  catch the **date** in first csv as variable, then find this date in second.csv, once dates are located, find the **lemon** for both with "date-location"

The "third.csv" seems to have **14 rows** and it may have **8**, in my computer appears:

Date,Lemon
1974-12-31,19
Date,Lemon
1975-01-02,18
.
.
.
Date,Lemon
1975-01-09,15

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this, I took a quick and dirty procedural  approach instead of an OO one. I also took a peek at the other answer and I see he parsed out the datetimes. I decided not to since you weren't doing any math specifically based on that. However his answer would be more flexible as with datetimes you can do more operations in the future.

```
        List<string> csvfile1Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file1.csv").ToList();
        List<string> csvfile2Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file2.csv").ToList();


        Dictionary<string, double> csv1Formatted = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        Dictionary<string, double> csv2Formatted = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        Dictionary<string, double> csv3Formatted = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        foreach (string line in csvfile1Text)
        {
          var temp=  line.Split(',');
            csv1Formatted.Add(temp[0], Double.Parse(temp[1]));

        }
        foreach (string line in csvfile2Text)
        {
            var temp = line.Split(',');
            csv2Formatted.Add(temp[0], Double.Parse(temp[1]));

        }

        //operation 1
        var penultimate = csv1Formatted["1974-01-03"];
        var corrsponding = csv2Formatted["1974-01-03"];
        var difference = penultimate - corrsponding;

        //operation 2
        var start = csv2Formatted["1974-01-03"];
        var end = csv2Formatted["1974-01-09"];
        var intermediate = csv2Formatted.Keys.SkipWhile((element => element != "1974-01-03")).ToList();
        Dictionary<string, double> newCSV2 = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        foreach (string element in intermediate)
        {
           var found = csv2Formatted[element];
           found = found + difference;
            newCSV2.Add(element, found);

        }

        //operation 3
        intermediate = csv1Formatted.Keys.TakeWhile((element => element != "1975-01-03")).ToList();
        foreach (string element in intermediate)
        {
            var found = csv1Formatted[element];
            csv3Formatted.Add(element, found);

        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,double> kvp in newCSV2)
        {
            csv3Formatted.Add(kvp.Key,kvp.Value);

        }

        //writing CSV3
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string,double> kvp in csv3Formatted)
        {

            sb.AppendLine(kvp.Key + "," + kvp.Value);

        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\csv3.csv", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, it pop-up a **System.FormatException** in line `csv1Formatted.Add(temp[0], Double.Parse(temp[1]));`

Comment: I will go through and revise it later when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite to use with CSV
https://github.com/kentcb/KBCsv

and if you want to work with csv entries as model for each row: 
http://www.filehelpers.net/quickstart/

I hope you find this helpful. 
Good luck :) Enjoy coding