# Cutting up a CSV file using split

Tags: vb.net, csv, split

I have a csv file, when i use the split function, my issue is that the 16th segment of the array has a name in it (in most cases) that has first and last name split by a comma. This obviously causes me issues as it puts my array out of sync. any suggestions on how i can handle this?

the string in the 16th segment is surrounded by "" if that helps, the split function still splits it though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456850/split-a-string-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-double-quotes-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

you can use [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1103809/525251)

Comment: i am not sure this will help me, i am not loloking for a whole new method of parsing the text file, just how to handle the use of a comma inside a "field".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: looking at the link above would this also split the comma's within the ""?

Comment: you can set TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes=true to escape comma inside quoted field

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Lumen CSV Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), it can correctly handle field values with commas.
Also it has a very good performance, and a very simple usage.
See the link above, it won't disappoint you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point.  Split is only good for simple csv parsing.  Anything that gets even a little complicated means a lot of extra code. Something like the TextFieldParser is better suited to what you want.  However if you must use Split here's one way:

```
    Dim TempArray() As String
    Dim Output As New List(Of String)
    If SourceString.Contains("""") Then
        TempArray = SourceString.Split(""""c)
        Output.AddRange(TempArray(0).Split(","c))
        Output.Add(TempArray(1))
        'If the quoted part of the csv line is at the end of the line omit this statement.
        Output.AddRange(TempArray(2).Split(","c))
    Else
        Output = New List(Of String)(SourceString.Split(","c))
    End If
```

This assumes that the data is strictly organized, except for the quotes, if not you'll have to add validation code.

Answer (score 0):

Split by "," ***with the quotes*** instead of just a comma.  Don't forget to take care of the first and last quotes on the line.