# is there any way to insert data from text file to dataset?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have text file that looks like this:

```
1 \t a
2 \t b
3 \t c
4 \t d
```

i have dataset:  `DataSet ZX = new DataSet();`

is there any way for inserting the text file values to this dataset ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to parse the file manually. Maybe like this:

```
string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");

DataRow row = null;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable tab = new DataTable();

tab.Columns.Add("First");
tab.Columns.Add("Second");

string[] rows = data.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string r in rows)
{
    string[] columns = r.Split(new char[] { '\t' },   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (columns.Length <= tab.Columns.Count)
    {
        row = tab.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
            row[i] = columns[i];

         tab.Rows.Add(row);
     }
 }

 ds.Tables.Add(tab);
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't know how many columns in the text file you can modify my original example as the following (assuming that the number of columns is constant for all rows):

```
// ...
string[] columns = r.Split(new char[] { '\t' },  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (tab.Columns.Count == 0)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
        tab.Columns.Add("Column" + (i + 1));
}

if (columns.Length <= tab.Columns.Count)
{
// ...
```

Also remove the initial creation of table columns:

```
// tab.Columns.Add("First");
// tab.Columns.Add("Second")
```

-- Pavel

Comment: thanks for the help, but what i can do when i dont know how many columns in my text file ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure there is,

Define a `DataTable`, Add `DataColumn` with data types that you want,

`ReadLine` the file, split the values by tab, and add each value as a `DataRow` to DataTable by calling `NewRow`.

There is a nice sample code at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), take a look and follow the steps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, create data tabel on the fly, refer [this article](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/data-table-csharp.aspx) for how-to

Read your file line by line and add those value to your data table , refer [this article](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx) for how-to read text file

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private DataTable GetTextToTable(string path)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable
        {
            Columns = {
                {"MyID", typeof(int)},
                "MyData"
            },
            TableName="MyTable"
        };
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            String line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = line.Split(new string[] { "\\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                dataTable.Rows.Add(words[0], words[1]);
            }
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }

}
```

Call it like

```
GetTextToTable(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("."), "TextFile.txt"));
```

You could also check out [`CSV File Imports in .NET`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1898)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like also to add to the "volpan" code the following :

```
String _source = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1253));
```

It's good to add the encoding of your text file, so you can be able to read the data and in my case export those after modification to another file.