# Parse CSV On Windows Phone

Tags: json, windows-phone-7

Hi I want to parse A CSV Response i am getting from a site. The original format is supposed to be in UTF-8 Json but i gathered it is not valid Json and can be parsed as CSV. I need a parser or a solution to help me parse the response which i intend to save in my isolated storage.

An Example of the response is as below . ( *I Wish To Ignore First Line Too*)

[4, "1.0", 1353586383652]

> [1, "Milburn Drive", "U3", 1353586717000]
>
> [1, "Milburn Drive", "U1", 1353587185000]
>
> [1, "Milburn Drive", "U5", 1353587151000]
>
> [1, "Milburn Drive", "U3", 1353587716000]
>
> [1, "Milburn Drive", "U3", 1353587530000]

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Isn't csv just text anyways? You could just use String functions (split, etc.?)

See this SO question, might be of use: [WP7 - read from CSV file? Or what to do with the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681023/wp7-read-from-csv-file-or-what-to-do-with-the-data)

Comment: Yes I could but i need  very efficient parser not just Split method. That is a  last resort.