# how to parse local CSV file wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, csv

Am developing an wp7 application in that i need read the CSV file and store into list

the csv file is 20 lines with first name, last name separated by ,(comma)

and i tried to use http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/ this and http://www.codeproject.com/articles/25133/linq-to-csv-library when am tring to include those dlls am getting **"windows phone projects will work only with windows phone assemblies" error**

how can i parse csv file in windows phone 7

thanks in advance

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/4681085/168097

Comment: @Circadian am new to C# and how can i use `streamreader` can u please give some istructions

Answer (score 0):

Use IsolatedStorageFileStream to get and open the file from saved path location.
Then read with StreamReader object.

```
    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = storage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {
      string line;
      while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        string[] temp1Arr = line.Split(',');

        //Manipulate your string values stored in array here 
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps!