# XML serialization error on Universal Store App

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, serialization

On a Universal App project I'm trying to deserialize a XML file, in the Windows version it works fine but in Windows Phone I ran into the following error:

> {System.InvalidOperationException: global::App.Data.DataItem cannot be
>   serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read2_DataItem
>   (Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read3_ArrayOfDataItem()}

How can I solve this? My code: [[link]](http://pastebin.com/dpX9Xs9X)

Comment: Maybe this will help, I wrote it awhile back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788238/deleting-on-array-item-in-windows-phone-c-sharp-app-and-never-show-it-in-next-ap/24792062#24792062

Comment: Serialization needs parameterless constructor, even if you don't use it. Try to add in `DataItem` class: `public DataItem() { UniqueID = string.Empty; Title = string.Empty; ... }`

Comment: @celsoap if you could post the code for the deserialization?

Comment: I have followed @Romasz suggestion and replaced my internal constructor for that one. Now it works perfectively on both plataforms.