# How can I split my stock quotes data into List?

Tags: c#, split

I've got a huge string with stock quotes information. It looks like this:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2016-05-06,49.919998,50.389999,49.66,50.389999,24715600,50.389999
2016-05-05,49.869999,50.299999,49.73,49.939999,25309500,49.939999
2016-05-04,49.84,50.060001,49.459999,49.869999,24171400,49.869999...........
```

How can I package it into generic `List<Stock>`:

```
Stock hs = new Stock();
hs.Date = Convert.ToDateTime();
hs.Open = Convert.ToDouble();
etc.

MyList.Add(hs)
```

Comment: Step 1 - split the one big string into lines. Step 2 - split each line into separate values (a string array, using `string.Split`). Step 3 - convert each array of values into a `Stock`. LINQ will make the code for the last step simpler.

Comment: Have a look into this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898/csv-file-imports-in-net
or this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282999/reading-csv-file-and-storing-values-into-an-array

Comment: Are these quotes for the same stock? If not how do you differentiate the quotes of each stock?

Comment: @Steve Yes, There are quotes of Apple. I got stocks quotes info for the 5 year.

Comment: @Noooom Do you have single string or multiple strings? I don't see in your example two lines separated by any character.

Comment: @Noooom but your answer says you have multiple strings.

Comment: @HariPrasad Yes, because I choosed another way to realize it. In the first one I did it like this one `string data = web.DownloadString(string.Format("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={0}&c={1}", ticker, yearToStartFrom));` And It hadn't any columns or rows. That's why csv was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With following assumptions,

1. Every values is separated by `,` and your input is one long string with the mentioned pattern.
2. The first row has column names.

.You could do this using these `Linq` statements.

```
    string input = @"Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,AdjClose,
                    2016-05-06,49.919998,50.389999,49.66,50.389999,24715600,50.389999,
                    2016-05-05,49.869999,50.299999,49.73,49.939999,25309500,49.939999,
                    2016-05-04,49.84,50.060001,49.459999,49.869999,24171400,49.869999";

    var stacks = input.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Select((x,i)=> new {index= i/7, item=x }) // split with 7 columns
                      .Where(x=>x.index !=0) // skip header row.
                      .GroupBy(x=>x.index)                      
                      .Select(x=> new Stack() 
                             {
                                 Date = DateTime.ParseExact(x.First().item.Trim(),"yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                 Open = double.Parse(x.Skip(1).First().item),
                                 High = double.Parse(x.Skip(2).First().item),
                                 Low = double.Parse(x.Skip(3).First().item),
                                 Close = double.Parse(x.Skip(4).First().item),
                                 Volume = double.Parse(x.Skip(5).First().item),
                                 AdjClose = double.Parse(x.Skip(6).First().item),

                             })
                      .ToList();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qwKReH)

Answer (score 0):

So, I did it in this way:

My HisctoricalStock class:

```
public class HistoricalStock
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public double Open { get; set; }
        public double High { get; set; }
        public double Low { get; set; }
        public double Close { get; set; }
        public double Volume { get; set; }
        public double AdjClose { get; set; }
    }
```

And I solved my problem using external csv file (But it's optional).

```
List<HistoricalStock> retval = new List<HistoricalStock>();

                try
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("G:/Test.csv", web.DownloadString(string.Format("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={0}&c={1}", ticker, yearToStartFrom)));
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException exc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
                }

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("G:/Test.csv");

                string currentLine;
                List<string> stoksList = new List<string>();

                // while stockList isn't empty
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    stoksList.Add(currentLine);

                // First row is a header 
                stoksList.RemoveAt(0);

                foreach (string str in stoksList)
                {
                    string[] parsedString = str.Split(',');

                    HistoricalStock hs = new HistoricalStock();

                    hs.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(parsedString[0]);
                    hs.Open = Convert.ToDouble(parsedString[1]);
                    hs.High = Convert.ToDouble(parsedString[2]);
                    hs.Low = Convert.ToDouble(parsedString[3]);
                    hs.Close = Convert.ToDouble(parsedString[4]);
                    hs.Volume = Convert.ToDouble(parsedString[5]);
                    hs.AdjClose = Convert.ToDouble(parsedString[6]);

                    retval.Add(hs);
                }
```